# Convert a string time to milliseconds (string manipulation?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a time string with this format:

```
10h 30m 04s
```

I need a conversion to milliseconds.

Best approach here is using substring?

something like:

```
var hours = myStr.substring(0, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const timeStr = '10h 30m 04s'
const milliseconds  = timeStr.match(/\d+/g)
       .reduce((acc, cur, idx) => acc + cur * (Math.pow(60, (2 - idx))) * 1000, 0)
console.log(milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a really compact way using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), like so:

```js
const time = "10h 30m 04s";
const milliseconds = time.split(" ").reduce((total, v, i) => { 
     return total + parseInt(v) * 1000 * (60**(2-i));
}, 0);
console.log(milliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a constant string representation where we have a space between each element, then it's easy enough string manipulation. We first split apart the string into separate parts (hours, minutes, seconds). For each part, we then cast it into an integer using `parseInt` (which handles discarding the single character at the end of the part, such as `h`). Finally, we convert the numeric representation into milliseconds using constant of the value in milliseconds (e.g. 1 hour in milliseconds).

```js
const string = "10h 30m 04s";
const [hours, mins, secs] = string.split(" ").map((s) => parseInt(s));
const milliseconds = secs * 1000 + (mins * 60000) + (hours * 3600000);
console.log(milliseconds)
```